# How to create a JButton with unicode image in Java?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jbutton

I have the following code :

```
  JButton Get_Unicode_Button(String unicodeText)
  {
    JButton button=new JButton("\\u"+unicodeText);
//    JButton button=new JButton("\u2605");
//    JButton button=new JButton("\u267b");
//    JButton button=new JButton("\u1F602");  // ?
    return button;
  }
```

I want to get a button displaying an image from unicode, I have a list of unicodes like this : "2605", "267b", "1F602", but it seems the way I implemented it above doesn't work, what's the right way to do it ?

Especially the 3rd line "\u1F602", even if I hard code it like above, it won't work, why ?

Comment: The first two should work fine, but you may have to use surrogates for the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it :

```
  JButton Get_Unicode_Button(String unicodeText)
  {
    int emojiCodePoint=Integer.parseInt(unicodeText,16);
    String emojiAsString=new String(Character.toChars(emojiCodePoint));
    JButton button=new JButton(emojiAsString);
    return button;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you converting your String to bytes and back to a String again?  As soon as you do `new String(Character.toChars(emojiCodePoint))`, you already have the correct String.  There is no reason whatsoever to involve bytes.