# How to save font file in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, fonts

This question is related to my previous question : [How to create a JButton with unicode image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859701/how-to-create-a-jbutton-with-unicode-image-in-java)

My app works fine when I run it from Netbeans IDE, but after I packaged it into a jar file and run from another system, some images won't show up properly, as mentioned in this question : [In Java how to detect if a unicode image can be displayed in a JButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874439/in-java-how-to-detect-if-a-unicode-image-can-be-displayed-in-a-jbutton)

So this question is : is there a way to first detect then save the font file when my app is running properly [ all images show up correctly ] with Netbeans, so I can package this font file into the jar file to be run in other environments ?

Edit : please pay attention to what I am asking :

**[1] How to detect where the font file is ?**

**[2] How to save the detected font file ?**

If you think another question can answer my question, does it have Java sample code to do the above 2 things ? If it does, can you cut and paste the sample code here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a custom font in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java)

Comment: I've looked at that question, it didn't tell me how to first detect and then save the font file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java

Comment: Or are you unsure of how to package it as a resource into the jar as well?

Comment: Question 3861989 didn't show me how to save the font file ? Any sample code showing how to do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056682/how-can-my-java-program-store-files-inside-of-its-jar-file

Comment: I don't see any code for saving the font file, how to do it ?

Comment: It's not code, it has to do with compilation